# Авторизация в WebView(Android)

Tags: java, android, api, webview

Есть сайт http://stud.knutd.com.ua/ 
Загружаю его через webView хочу чтобы автоматически происходила авторизация. 
webView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword("http://stud.knutd.com.ua/", "Application", "log", "pass");
Не работает.
Как еще можно реализовать такой функционал?

Comment: Автоматическая?... Ну, попробуйте вбивать логин и паполь в поля. Что происходит при клике на кнопку - это секрет, вам это автоматически не реализовать

Comment: Тогда можно хоть как-то запоминать пароль и логин, как это делает браузер?